# `Failed to execute script entry_point` in Anaconda3.sh

Tags: docker, ubuntu, jupyter-notebook, anaconda3

I want to use jupyter notbook by using Anaconda3 in docker ubuntu, but when I create an image with `docker build --platform linux/amd64 .` the following error occurs.

How can I solve it?

```
#8 141.1 
#8 141.1 2022-05-05 04:21:55 (3.62 MB/s) - 'Anaconda3-2019.10-Linux-x86_64.sh' saved [530308481/530308481]
#8 141.1 
#8 141.3 PREFIX=/opt/anaconda3
#8 143.4 Unpacking payload ...
                                                                                          [96] Failed to execute script entry_point concurrent.futures.process._RemoteTraceback: 
#8 151.7 '''
#8 151.7 Traceback (most recent call last):
#8 151.7   File "concurrent/futures/process.py", line 367, in _queue_management_worker
#8 151.7   File "multiprocessing/connection.py", line 251, in recv
#8 151.7 TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'msg'
#8 151.7 '''
#8 151.7 
#8 151.7 The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
#8 151.7 
#8 151.7 Traceback (most recent call last):
#8 151.7   File "entry_point.py", line 71, in <module>
#8 151.7   File "concurrent/futures/process.py", line 483, in _chain_from_iterable_of_lists
#8 151.7   File "concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 598, in result_iterator
#8 151.7   File "concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 435, in result
#8 151.7   File "concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 384, in __get_result
#8 151.7 concurrent.futures.process.BrokenProcessPool: A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending.
------ executor failed running [/bin/sh -c wget https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2019.10-Linux-x86_64.sh && sh /opt/Anaconda3-2019.10-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -p /opt/anaconda3 &&     rm -f Anaconda3-2019.10-Linux-x86_64.sh]: exit code: 1
```

The Dockerfile is like below:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

# update
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y \
    sudo \
    wget \
    vim

#install anaconda3
WORKDIR /opt
# download anaconda package and install anaconda
# archive -> https://repo.continuum.io/archive/
RUN wget https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2019.10-Linux-x86_64.sh && \
    sh /opt/Anaconda3-2019.10-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -p /opt/anaconda3 && \
    rm -f Anaconda3-2019.10-Linux-x86_64.sh
# set path
ENV PATH /opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH

# update pip and conda
RUN pip install --upgrade pip

WORKDIR /
RUN mkdir /work

# execute jupyterlab as a default command
CMD ["jupyter", "lab", "--ip=0.0.0.0", "--allow-root", "--LabApp.token=''"]
```

---

Mac 12.3.1 Apple M1

Docker desktop for Mac 4.7.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be a space issue during the installation, I was getting the exact error. If you accept the default option to install Anaconda on the “default path” Anaconda is installed in your user home directory, where space can be an issue. For me it got resolved when changed the default directory to some other directory during installation .You can also refer this page for similar issues- https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/10143